# PHP create sqlite db in memory and save result on filesystem later

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

im trying to create sqlite database in ram, populate it with data IN RAM (thousands of insert calls), and then save resultant dataset on filesystem...

Can I do that?

I instantiate handle and create schema like this:

```
// Create new database in memory
$memoryDb = new \PDO('sqlite::memory:');
$schema = <<<EOT
CREATE TABLE `blahh` (
    `JSON`           BLOB,
    `DR_ID`    INTEGER,
    `SOURCE_ID`    INTEGER,
    `UUID`         TEXT
)
EOT;
$memoryDb->exec($schema);
//Loading with data - not shown as irrelevant
```

^How would I save above in-memory sqlite representation on FS?

Comment: If the PHP sqlite bindings support the [backup API](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html), it's easy, but easiest is just using a file based database from the start.